# HTMLAgilityPack Exclude by classes

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I have a Ul element that has 3 different types of li children, I want to exclude 2 of these types of children by their class. exclude li elements with class = map and class = map-button

Here is what I am fiddling with,

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Constants.New_York.GetOffenderPageById(""+ 41586));

var querylist3 = from list in 
                   doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='address label-value']")
                  .Cast<HtmlNode>()
  from row in list.SelectNodes("not(li[@class='map']) and not(li[@class='map-button'])")
                  .Cast<HtmlNode>()
  select new { CellText = Utilities.RemoveHtmlCharacters(row.InnerText) };

foreach (var q1 in querylist3)
        Console.WriteLine(q1.CellText);
```

So I was looking at [HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes expression to ignore an element with a certain attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225438/htmlagilitypack-selectnodes-expression-to-ignore-an-element-with-a-certain-attri) but either I cannot properly understand the solution or it's not working.

I prefer not to create object instance and compare with linq...

For reference this is the HTML,

```
<ul class="address label-value">
   <li><span class="label">Type</span><span class="value">RES&nbsp;(Primary)</span></li>
   <li><span class="label">County</span><span class="value">Suffolk</span></li>
   <li class="no-border-bottom"><span class="label">Address</span><span class="value">1010 OLD MEDFORD RD<br>FARMINGVILLE,&nbsp;New York&nbsp;11738</span></li>
   <li class="map-button"><a class="cta cta-blue cta-small" href="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDLQ6Qf1v0RJyudkTTEcAYsXPIewwO4F3w&amp;zoom=17&amp;q=1010 OLD MEDFORD RD,FARMINGVILLE,NY,11738">View on Map</a></li>
   <li class="map">
      <iframe src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="map-iframe">&lt;!----&gt;</iframe>
      <p><a href="../nsor/mapping-exceptions.htm">Learn about possible mapping exceptions.</a></p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer isn't what I was hoping to learn... but it solved it. I still would like to know how to use not within the search parameters of htmlnode select...

I temporarily used linq... Not sure which is better or anything...

```
 var querylist3 = from list in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class='address label-value']").Cast<HtmlNode>()
                     from row in list.SelectNodes("li").Where(x => !x.Attributes.Contains("class") || !x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("map")).Cast<HtmlNode>()
                     select new { CellText = Utilities.RemoveHtmlCharacters(row.InnerText) };
```